# Jquery <<S.fn.init [selector]>> in Java Script Vanilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, events

For this project, I want to change the logic written in jquery with that in js vanilla.

**My code looks like this**
Based on the information from the `input` using the event `keydown`,
I call a function through which I do a search in `api`.

```
 var selectedUsers = [] //empty array

$('#userSearchTextbox').keydown((event)=>{

     var textBox = $(event.target);
     var value = textBox.val();

     //Function which search in api
     searchUsers(value);
 
 });

//Search in array function
function searchUsers(searchTerm){
    $.get("/api/users",{search:searchTerm},results =>{
        outputSelectableUsers(results,$('.resultsContainer'));
    });
  }
```

After I call another function `outputSelectableUsers`
which will call 2 functions one that displays the data in HTML and one that creates an array of values.

function outputSelectableUsers(results,container){

```
    results.forEach(results => {

        //Call function which will render the html         
        var html =createUserHtml(results,false);


        /*
        Here is the problem, as seen using jquery element variable selects html variable which render function
        */
        var element = $(html);
        
        /*
        with jquery, I managed to select the variable and assign it a click event that when I click it calls the function that adapts the array with data
        from each API call
        */
        element.click(()=>userSelected(results))
        

        //append content to the html selector
        container.append(element);
    });


}

//Function which will update the array
function userSelected(user){
    selectedUsers.push(user);  
}
```

**This is what the visible result looks like**
[image]

And when I click on one of the cards, the area adapts to the user's values.
[image]

values ​​that I take from the array and enter them in the database.

I managed to convert everything to js using `fetch` instead of `ajax jquery` and changed the `selectors and events` with `vanilla js code`.

**But the problem is I couldn't find a way to change this piece of code.**

```
var html =createUserHtml(results,false);
var element = $(html);
console.log(element)
element.click(()=>userSelected(results))
container.append(element);
```

at `consol.log (element)` I observed asata in the console.
[image]

The question is could I choose the element with js vanilla and get the same result as in the jquery version. To use Js Vanilla code instead of

```
    var element = $(html);
    element.click(()=>userSelected(results))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let users_id = results._id;

        let html = createUserHtml(results,users_id ,false);
        container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',html);
        //Identify each element by a unique selector
        document.querySelector(`[data-selectorTab ="${results._id}"]`).addEventListener('click',()=>{
            userSelected(res)
        })
```

I solve this by adding a data attribute to dinamically generated elements,using this data atribute I can make a individual selector for each user.